# Обход коллекции Map в порядке добавления элементов

Tags: java, map

Пытаюсь реализовать метод, который будет конвертировать римские цифры в арабские. Вот код:

```java
public static String convertToRoman(int number) {
    Map<String, Integer> roman = new TreeMap<>();

    roman.put("M", 1000);
    roman.put("CM", 900);
    roman.put("D", 500);
    roman.put("CD", 400);
    roman.put("C", 100);
    roman.put("XC", 90);
    roman.put("L", 50);
    roman.put("XL", 40);
    roman.put("X", 10);
    roman.put("IX", 9);
    roman.put("V", 5);
    roman.put("IV", 4);
    roman.put("I", 1);

    String result = "";

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> elem : roman.entrySet()) {
        int repeat = (int) Math.floor(number / elem.getValue());
        number -= repeat * elem.getValue();
        result += elem.getKey().repeat(repeat);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Как мне организовать обход коллекции в порядке добавления элементов, т.е. чтобы сначала в `elem` попадал `М:1000`, потом `СМ:900` и т.д.?

Answer (score 2):

Никак. `Map` не хранит порядок добавления элементов. Вам нужно использовать другую структуру данных.
Например `LinkedHashMap` как подсказали в комментариях.

Если вам важен порядок возможно вам стоит хранить это не как `Map`, а как объект с двумя полями и так же использовать `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 2):

В классе `Collections` есть статический метод [singletonMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap(K,%20V)) на такой случай. Можно, например, создать коллекцию `List<Map<String, Integer>>`:

```java
List<Map<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(Collections.singletonMap("M", 1000));
list.add(Collections.singletonMap("CM", 900));
list.add(Collections.singletonMap("D", 500));
list.add(Collections.singletonMap("CD", 400));
list.add(Collections.singletonMap("C", 100));
list.add(Collections.singletonMap("XC", 90));
list.add(Collections.singletonMap("L", 50));
list.add(Collections.singletonMap("XL", 40));
list.add(Collections.singletonMap("X", 10));
list.add(Collections.singletonMap("IX", 9));
list.add(Collections.singletonMap("V", 5));
list.add(Collections.singletonMap("IV", 4));
list.add(Collections.singletonMap("I", 1));
```

Открыть по этой коллекции итератор:

```java
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> iterator =
        list.stream().flatMap(element -> element.entrySet().stream()).iterator();
```

Обход коллекции итератором:

```java
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
int number = 1822;

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = iterator.next();
    String key = entry.getKey();
    int value = entry.getValue();
    int quantity = number / value;
    number -= quantity * value;
    result.append(key.repeat(quantity));
}

System.out.println(result.toString()); // MDCCCXXII
```

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае лучше использовать [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), где порядок элементов соответствует порядку их добавления. При последующем изменении существующего значения по ключу порядок остается прежним.

```java
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

map.put("M", 1000);
map.put("CM", 900);
map.put("D", 500);
map.put("CD", 400);
map.put("C", 100);
map.put("XC", 90);
map.put("L", 50);
map.put("XL", 40);
map.put("X", 10);
map.put("IX", 9);
map.put("V", 5);
map.put("IV", 4);
map.put("I", 1);

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
int number = 1822;

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    int value = entry.getValue();
    int quantity = number / value;
    number -= quantity * value;
    result.append(key.repeat(quantity));
}

System.out.println(result.toString()); // MDCCCXXII
```